# Accept Spanish Unicode Chars in JS Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I have the following regex set up to accept words and some special characters:

```
const regex = /^[\w\-'.,?\/()\[\]!&\s]+$/;
```

I want to extend this to also include the range of special characters in Spanish: `ñáéíóú`

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50178498/no-pl-for-javascript-regex-use-unicode-in-js-regex) which provides a regex for all special chars, but I'm not sure how to incorporate this kind of solution into my already existing regex.

Comment: Change `\w` to `\wñáéíóú`?

Comment: I don't need to use the unicode syntax? `\u2000` etc?

Comment: No, that is not needed.

Comment: Ok cool, wanna post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add those characters to the class you already have in your regex:

```
const regex = /^[\wñáéíóú\-'.,?\/()\[\]!&\s]+$/;
```

It is not needed to add the `u` modifier.

NB: it is not really necessary to escape the `[` character inside a character class.